# Correct syntax for Apache If expressions with mod_macro

Tags: apache-2.4

I'm trying to exploit the power of Apache 2.4's `<If>` directives to customize a `<Macro>` by evaluating its parameters.

I'm currently trying to do the following:

- If authenticationMode == "htpasswd" use `.htpasswd` file
- If authenticationMode == "server" use `pwauth`
- Else break Apache configuration

The following code (inside of a `<Macro>` tag) does not work

```
        SetEnv ROOT_PATH /somewhere #Set outside macro

        <If "$authenticationMode == 'htpasswd'"> # Guilty line!
            AuthUserFile $ROOT_PATH/path/to/.htpasswd
        </If>
        <ElseIf "$authenticationMode == 'server'">
            AuthBasicProvider external
            AuthExternal pwauth
        </ElseIf>
        <Else>
            DO_CRASH
        </Else>
```

Error message is `Cannot parse condition clause: syntax error, unexpected T_OP_STR_EQ, expecting '('`

How to fix?

Comment: Aren't you mixing the concept of <Macro>, which is evaluated once at start up, and the <If> concept, which is evaluated for each request?

Comment: I don't see any use of mod_macro (`<Macro …>…</Macro>` and `Use`) in this code. Are you sure, mod_macro is involved here?

Comment: Yes, because that is the *fragment* of a Macro. If @Zimmi is right, then the answer is that <If>s cannot be used in <Macro>s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `<If>` inside a `<Macro>`, but not to customize a `<Macro>` with `<If>`.

As mentioned in my comment, the `<Macro>` is evaluated only at start up, and `<If>` are evaluated for each incoming request.

To solve your problem, put your `$authenticationMode` variable into single quotes, because it is a string (as you have done for the right part):

```
<If "'$authenticationMode' == 'htpasswd'">
```

But what this macro will do is as follow:

At start up you have somewhere in your config the instruction `Use mymacro $param`

The [mod_macro](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_macro.html) doc says:

> At server startup time, each of these Use invocations would be
>   expanded into a full virtualhost (*), as described by the Macro
>   definition.

(* = The example in the doc is about virtualhosts)

So if you have `Use mymacro htpasswd`, it will expand to following config:

```
<If "'htpasswd' == 'htpasswd'"> # Guilty line!
    AuthUserFile $ROOT_PATH/path/to/.htpasswd
</If>
<ElseIf "'htpasswd' == 'server'">
    AuthBasicProvider external
    AuthExternal pwauth
</ElseIf>
<Else>
    DO_CRASH
</Else>
```

This will test for each request some not very usefull conditions. And your server will never start because of the DO_CRASH instruction.

As alternative way, I would think about writing 2 macros: one corresponding to the authenticationMode == "htpasswd" and another for the authenticationMode == "server".

Please test and and take into account that I'm still learning Apache 2.4, so it may not be complete answer... Hope this helps!

A good read of [Apache's expression doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/expr.html) could be useful too.

Comment: The two-macros option (actually 4, because that's not the only one) seems the only viable option

Comment: I don't see why `<If "'htpasswd' == 'htpasswd'">` would evaluate to false. Yes, it would be wasteful re-evaluating it on every request, but it ought to still have the correct effect, surely?